# PC game involving time-traveling fighters, maybe with digitized sprites like Mortal Kombat, included a Roman centurion I think

Tags: story-identification, video-games

I remember seeing the demo for this on BBS systems somewhere around 1994-2000. I have somewhat foggy memories where I think I remember seeing demo images, and trying to download the demo, only to find that it downloaded far too slowly on our connection, meaning it would time out before completion. My memory of it was large sprites, like the early *Mortal Kombat*, but in retrospect, it was probably much more modest — I still remember the *Street Fighter 2* port, and *Sango Fighter*, running very slowly with more modest figures. Unfortunately, the only character that's stuck with me was a Roman character who had a cloak (purple?), with I think the still demo image showing him either opening it to fire off a fireball, or being able to block with it.

I am 90% certain that the concept of the game involved fighters pulled from various eras of time and that the title had some misspelled words, possibly to cash in on the *Mortal Kombat* cachet.

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=K5xMlkRak_w - Blandia?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cVDEC4bO2g0 - World Heroes?

Comment: https://www.reddit.com/r/tipofmyjoystick/comments/kh0rdf/arcadepre1995fighting_game_with_a_romangreek/ - Guy looking for possibly the same game

Comment: Neither of those match, but the raft bit sounds vaguely familiar...

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1RG1UCD3XTc - Deadliest Warrior? (although the timescale is wrong)

Comment: Are you sure you're not looking for time travelling robots?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ah! Trolling through games on Dosgames.com, I found it, I think. *[Brudal Baddle: The Quest for Talis Ra](https://www.mobygames.com/game/brudal-baddle)*.

> *Brudal Baddle* is a one-on-one fighting game. The story behind this title is that in 2023 at a laboratory in Los Alamos, Dr Chen found a way to punch holes in the fabric of space and time. A number of attempts to punch holes to the past had been successful, but on the first attempt to make a hole through to the future disaster struck. A cyborg like creature, Talis Ra, came through the hole, killed Dr Chen, and stole the equipment. Now all the holes have guardians on the other side, the player must take the form of one of the guardians and battle through all the holes to meet and defeat Talis Ra.

The graphics were cruder than I remembered... And I think it was Brudus that I recalled, who has a red cloak.

[image: Screenshot of Brudal Baddle]

### Gameplay

Comment: All those sprites with cocked fists... Reading the quote I am forced to picture Dr. Chen, fists up, literally _punching_ holes in space.